# Альтернативные ресурсы для устройств с разной минимальной высотой экрана

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-xml

У меня в папке `res/layout` лежит верстка для устройств со стандартной высотой и шириной экрана. К примеру (720*1280 и его минимальная высота 640dp), но на устройствах Nexus кнопки управления находятся на экране и занимают какую-то его часть, поэтому мои макеты, к примеру, на Nexus 4 (768*1280), уже не смотрятся. Для этого я создаю новую папку с квалификатором, который соответствует минимальной высоте 592dp - `layout-h592dp`, но Nexus ее не видит и берет ресурсы со стандартной папки, если же я поменяю квалификатор на `layout-h560dp`, то Nexus ее видит и берет из нее ресурсы, но при этом с нее берет ресурсы и устройство у которого `h640dp`. Получается, что для Nexus и для обычных экранов мне нужно создать две папки h560dp и h600dp?

Я наверное что-то упустил, или неправильно делаю, помогите разобраться?

И еще вопрос, почему, когда я меряю  высоту таким способом:

```
public static int getShDp(Activity activity){
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int ht = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int shDp = (int) ScreenHelper.convertPixelsToDp(ht, activity);
    return shDp;
}
```

а потом создаю папку с квалификатором равным значению `shDp = 592dp`, то оттуда ресурсы не берутся, пока я не понижу до h560dp ? Значение shDp = 592dp это  с учетом или без учета системных кнопок на экране?

Comment: у вас абсолютные значения в позиционировании элементов используются или чем вызвано то, что разница высоты в пару десятков *dp* ломает макет?

Comment: да, используются абсолютные значения!