# Как загрзить layout из нужной папки вручную

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-resources, android-xml

Мне нужно что бы для устройств у которых есть системный **NavigationBar** я мог загрузить файлы разметки из другой папки. Или лучше просто значения из **res/dimen**,  Каким образом можно сказать из какой папки нужно загружать ресуры? и как эта папка должна называться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете для таких целей создать отдельные layout-файлы, например. 
Есть у вас, к примеру, `activity_main.xml`. Вы копируете его, и называете копию `navbar_activity_main`. И в самой Activity проверяете, есть ли навбар, или нет, и в зависимости от этого выставляете определенный `xml`.

Так, чтобы определяла это все сама система, я думаю, сделать невозможно.

Comment: Получается я не могу программно сказать проложения, что если есть навбар, то все ресурсы нужно брать с "подходящей папки" ? Как вы адаптируете приложение для Nexus устройств?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, никак. Навбар по своей сути не должен влиять ни на что, кроме размера жисплея. А размер может быть в теории таким же, даже и без навбара, т. к. нету никаких ограничений на разрешение, размер дисплея, и на соотношение сторон. В идеале, ваше приложение не должно зависить от навбара вообще

Comment: а каким еще способом можно это риализовать? я пробовал через sH но возникли проблемы, их  я описал в этом вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534975/191718